# Regular Expression search and replace with 2 conditions

Tags: regex

I want to do a search and replace within a file.

The search will be for a filename (within a text file) that its extension is .xml.
Find the location by the .xml extension and change the text right before it.

i.e, find this line with "emission_mazda_3_c1_zjz6_16_**05**_ho2s_front.xml" text and replace the text to "emission_mazda_3_c1_zjz6_16_**04**_ho2s_front.xml".

Any help will be appreciated,
Thanks
Tommy

Comment: Will they always be in this format? What's the most generic way you can express these files names (while still being consistent)?

Answer (score 0):

It depends slightly on what you are using the regex in, so I have given a couple of examples.

Using BRE you could use:

```
s/\(emission_mazda_3_c1_zjz6_16_\)\(05\)\(_ho2s_front.xml\)/\104\3/
```

Which as Vim uses BRE, to do this on the whole document would be:

```
%s/\(emission_mazda_3_c1_zjz6_16_\)\(05\)\(_ho2s_front.xml\)/\104\3/
```

Or with sed, which also uses BRE, to output to stdout the file `input.txt` with the replacements made:

```
sed -e 's/\(emission_mazda_3_c1_zjz6_16_\)\(05\)\(_ho2s_front.xml\)/\104\3/' input.txt
```

While with ERE you could use:

```
s/(emission_mazda_3_c1_zjz6_16_)(05)(_ho2s_front.xml)/\104\3/
```

The trick to all this is the use of backreferences.  The text between the first two `/` characters describes what you are looking for and is grouped by using the `()` characters. The text between the last two `/` characters is what you want to replace it with.  So you are saying replace the found text with the first group (`\1` signifies this), then put `04`, then add the third group (`\3` signifies this).